# How can I override devices section of docker-compose to remove a device

Tags: docker-compose

I have the following section in my `docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  demo:
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
```

That's great and working like a charm, however, I need to be able to do development also in a location where I don't have that device. I can't get `docker-compose.override.yaml` to just ignore that.

I have tried `devices: []`, but I am still getting:

> DT1001    Error response from daemon: error gathering device information
> while adding custom device "/dev/ttyUSB0": no such file or directory
> If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.

*[Update]*

That is not going to work like this. According to the documentation the "array" type parameters are merged. Hence there is no way to remove any of the elements in the override - which is quite a pitty. I had to restructure the definitions.